# Is data stored in an external object in Salesforce?

Tags: webservices, object, mulesoft

I am currently consuming a service from Mulesoft into Salesforce.
The requirement is that the data coming will not be stored anywhere in Salesforce.
I would like to know whether an external object in Salesforce stores the incoming data?

Also is there anywhere in Salesforce the data is getting stored?

Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_external_objects.htm):

> External objects are similar to custom objects, but external object
>   record data is stored outside your Salesforce organization.

An external object is a mapping of data from an external data source via the same type of metadata that normal Salesforce objects use so the information can be accessed and presented inside Salesforce easily. The data remains remote and is queried (or updated) as needed from (to) the external data source.

This mechanism is useful for example when there is an external "system of record" that contains a lot of data and you only need a small part of that data.